# Expresión regular que me valide numero pero que al comienzo obligatoriamente lo haga con 0

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

Mi consulta es la siguiente: Cómo puedo, mediante una expresión regular, validar un campo numérico y que al comienzo siempre lo haga con 0.  He visto varios ejemplos pero que al comienzo de la cadena sea 0, no. De ante mano agradezco su colaboración.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que quieres sería algo así
`/^0\d+$/`

En este enlace puedes probar la expresión: [RegExr](https://regexr.com/)

Pero para una validación tan simple, creo que no es buena idea usar regex.

Comment: Prefiero utilizaresto para probar:  https://regex101.com/r/DCuefV/1

Comment: Agradezco el apoyo, muy gentil

Comment: es que estoy intentando validar un RTN registro tributario en mi pais, y resulta que todos los DNI comienzan asi por eso quería tener una idea